# Extracted HTML data is empty

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
import pandas
from lxml import etree

class jd_commodity:
def __init__(self, name):
self.commodity_url = f"https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%7Bname%7D&enc=utf-8&wq=%7Bname%7D"
def jd_commodity_data(self):
res_True = 1
try:
res = requests.get(self.commodity_url, timeout=3)
while res_True:
if res.text == None:
res = requests.get(self.commodity_url, timeout=3)
else:
res_True = 0
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
print('访问超时了')
return
page = int(input('输入需要提取的页数'))
self.parse_data(res, self.commodity_url)
print(f"提取数据成功")
@staticmethod  
def parse_data(res, commodity_url):
if res.status_code == 200:
parsed = etree.HTML(res.text)
print(parsed)
categorys = parsed.xpath('//ul\[@class="J_valueList"\]/li/a/text()')
categorys_url = parsed.xpath('//ul\[@class="J_valueList"\]/li/a/@data-v')
categorys_all = dict(zip(categorys,categorys_url))
print(categorys)
```

In this code,sometimes category is empty. I suspect it may be an issue with the parsed variable, but when I print the parsed variable, it looks fine.I wanted to solve this problem, but I couldn't start.